# Can we create an iterator for a `std::vector` which increments over three values simultaneously?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, c++20

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve: Assume we are given a `std::vector<std::byte> rgb_data` containing RGB color values and a `struct rgb{ double r, g, b; };`. I would to create a `std::vector<rgb> transformed_rgb_data` containing these RGB color values using `std::transform`. Without `std::transform`, this could be done as follows:

```
std::size_t j = 0;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rgb_data.size(); i += 3)
{
    transformed_rgb_data = {
        static_cast<double>(rgb_data[i],
        static_cast<double>(rgb_data[i + 1],
        static_cast<double>(rgb_data[i + 2]
    };
}
```

Is there a mechanism in the standard library which allows me to construct an iterator for `rgb_data` which increments by `3` and references a `std::tuple` (I think that would be the best idea) which then is passed to the unary function passed to `std::transform`?

Comment: Shouldn't you also divide by 255.0 somewhere?

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's really only an illustrating example of something. So, please don't treat it too rigorously. The actual question can be answered more generally.

Comment: How about https://godbolt.org/z/Mq513Y5d7

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Let me introduce myself, I'm UB?

Comment: `boost::iterator_facade` could be used to implement what you want.

Comment: @Evg yes, technically. It should work everywhere though

Comment: Should it be `transformed_rgb_data[j++]`?

Answer (score 4):

The c++23 way would be by using [`std::views::adjacent_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/adjacent_view) (and its friend [`std::views::adjacent_transform_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/adjacent_transform_view)), which is doing exactly this but not many compilers are currently supporting it.

Comment: chunk_view seems more appropriate, adjacent_view creates a (overlapping) sliding window...

Answer (score 2):

- Create your own custom "RGB view" iterator that has an internal `uint8_t* p` pointer.
- When dereferenced, use the 3 adjacent bytes to construct the RGB struct and return it (something like `RGB{p[0], p[1], p[2]}`).
- When incremented, increment the pointer by 3.
- Make sure to specialize `std::iterator_traits` for your iterator
- Copy that into your RGB vector

```
std::vector<uint8_t> byteArray = ...;
std::vector<RGB> rgbArray(rgbaIter{byteArray.data()}, 
                          rgbaIter{byteArray.data() + byteArray.size()});

// Can also use vector::insert, std::copy, std::copy_n, etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might use `chunk` and `transform` view (equivalent should be in std in C+23):

```
std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto c : v | ranges::views::chunk(3) | ranges::views::transform([](auto r){
    return color{r[0] / 255., r[1] / 255., r[2] / 255.};
}))
{
    std::cout << c.r << " " << c.g << " " << c.b << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/joadq53PK)